# Git stash apply, asks to commit/stash change

Tags: git

When I use for example:

```
git stash apply stash@{6}
```

It says:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        [...]
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
```

So, I have to run:

```
git stash
```

after that, I usually click keyboard-up to repeat the first command.. but the stash@{6} is not valid anymore, now it will stash@{7}

How is your approach on that case?
Do I use git stash pop after?

Is there a more creative way to do that?

Comment: I didn't understand what the problem was. As you have already said, the approach is to use `git stash apply stash@{7}` then.

Comment: Is there a creative way to change to the stash@{6} in one simple line (directly) when there are changed files in your current environment?

Comment: If you got that error message when trying to apply a stash, it means that either your working directory or stage was dirty.  If you want that work, you should commit or stash it before trying to apply another stash.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah, but is there a way to force the stash to apply?

Comment: No I don't, but you almost certainly don't want to do this.

Comment: You could write a shell script or something like that which increments the stash number, but I'm not sure if it would be worth the effort.

Comment: Having this many stashes in the first place is a sign that you should learn to use branches. :-) I used to abuse `git stash` myself, but saved stashes are nothing more than commits that are hard to use. Make regular commits, which are easy to use, instead; life is better this way.